# Initial Firebase 9 connection refused

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to learn Firebase to add to my React project.  Many answers deal with older versions with Firebase.  Read that that Firebase 9 was a major update so difficult finding answers. I keep getting this error:

```
fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:270          POST http://localhost:8090/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel?database=projects%2Fabc-chart%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&VER=8&RID=41901&CVER=22&X-HTTP-Session-Id=gsessionid&%24httpHeaders=X-Goog-Api-Client%3Agl-js%2F%20fire%2F9.6.10%0D%0AContent-Type%3Atext%2Fplain%0D%0AX-Firebase-GMPID%3A1%3A177213787941%3Aweb%3A9f6ce48e7d16c61c3754cc%0D%0A&zx=7tsvfv2qwcyt&t=1 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

and this one:

```
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.6.10): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=unavailable]: The operation could not be completed
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

My firebase-config.js file, copied from Firebase as they suggest.

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getFirestore, connectFirestoreEmulator } from '@firebase/firestore'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};

// init firebase app
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// init services: used to reach out to get data
export const db = getFirestore(app);
connectFirestoreEmulator(db, 'localhost', 8090);
```

and the React file App.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { db } from './firebase-config';
import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';

function App() {
  const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);
  const studentCollectionRef = collection(db, "students");
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const getStudents = async () => {
      const data = await getDocs(studentCollectionRef);
      console.log(data);
    }

    getStudents()
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        Hey queen
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Did you enable Firestore in the Firebase Console?

Answer (score 1):

There are three things I can suggest based on what you've provided:

- If you are using env vars for your config make sure they are prepended with `REACT_APP`. Eg:

`apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY`

- Ensure your emulators are running before you `connectFirestoreEmulator` by running `firebase emulators:start` (optionally `firebase emulators: start --import ./path/to/firestore-data`)
- Make sure that the port specified in your `connectFirestoreEmulator` (8090) is the same as the port specified in your `firebase.json` file.