# Firestore query abnormally slow compared to other queries, sometimes fails

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, http-status-code-400

I am performing a firebase query in order to get tickets in a bugtracker app that belong to a specific project. When I load the page that uses this query, the data sometimes loads the data, and sometimes fails to load the data with this error message:

> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.6.10): Connection WebChannel
> transport errored

followed by a 400 POST error (also strange since I am not adding data to the database):

> fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:270          POST
> https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel?database=projects%2Fbugtracker-ad036%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&VER=8&gsessionid=WLlKfoxUAL-Qxt242-wHXlDzxIsUI23lt1Wynf2GhDs&SID=AD8kKCDnuwmxndB_gE1gag&RID=80048&AID=161539&zx=qnwq3itw57jk&t=1
> 400

Also, even if this query manages to work and data is displayed on screen, the process takes abnormally long compared to other queries (~8-10 seconds longer).

This is the specific query and snapshot I am using:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const ticketRef = collection(db, "tickets")
    const ticketQuery = query(ticketRef, orderBy("timeStamp", "desc"), where("projectId", "==", projectId), limit(5))
    

    const unsub = onSnapshot(ticketQuery, (snapshot) => 
      setTickets(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id:doc.id })))
    );   return unsub; });
```

Since I have been reading that the problem might be with how the app is caching data, I'll also include the config file in case that helps:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";


const firebaseConfig = {
  databaseURL: 'https://bugtracker-ad036.firebaseio.com',
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY,
  authDomain: "bugtracker-ad036.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "bugtracker-ad036",
  storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  appId: "1:XXXXXXXXXX:web:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXSS", 
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const auth = getAuth()
export const storage = getStorage(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

**For the error : @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.6.10): Connection WebChannel transport errored**

You can refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69758609/15774176):

> Most recent solution provided [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5667):
>
> ```
> import {initializeFirestore} from 'firebase/firestore'
>  const db = initializeFirestore(firebaseApp, {useFetchStreams: false})
> ```

**For slow Query performance you can refer to the reasons and resolution steps  mentioned this [blog](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-cloud-firestore-query-slow-e081fb8e55dd):**

> Probably the most common explanation for a seemingly slow query is
> that your query is, in fact, running very fast. But after the query is
> complete, we still need to transfer all of that data to your device,
> and that’s the part that’s running slowly.

**If  Your offline cache is too big:**

> - First, follow the best practices : add limits to your queries so    you’re only retrieving the data that you think your users will need,
>   and consider moving unneeded details into subcollections. Also, you
>   can follow the “several subcollections vs a separate top level
>   collection” discussion at the end of the [post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries.html), this would be a
>   good argument for the “several subcollections” structure, because the
>   cache only needs to search through the data in these smaller
>   collections.
> - Second, don’t stuff more data in the cache than you need. some cases    where developers will do this intentionally by querying a
>   massive    number of documents when their application first starts up,
>   then    forcing all future database requests to go through the local
>   cache,    usually in a scheme to reduce database costs, or make future
>   calls    faster. But in practice, this tends to do more harm than
>   good.
> - Third, consider reducing the size of your offline cache. The size of    your cache is set to 100MB on mobile devices by default, but in
>   some    situations, this might be too much data for your device to
>   handle,    particularly if you end up having most of your data in one
>   massive    collection. You can change this size by modifying the
>   [cacheSizeBytes    value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_cache_size) in your Firebase settings, and that’s
>   something you might    want to do for certain clients.
> - Fourth, try [disabling persistence entirely](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_persistence) and see what happens.    generally don’t recommend this approach — as the offline
>   cache is    pretty great. But if a query seems slow and you don’t know
>   why,    re-running your app with persistence turned off can give you a
>   good    idea if your cache is contributing to the problem.

For more information you can refer to the [stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46717898/15774176)  and [thread](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1868) where a similar issue has been mentioned.

Comment: With respect to the first suggestion, I have read on numerous posts that `useFetchStreams: false` was needed in projects that were migrating from v8 to v9 and were using React Native. Further, this option setting was meant to be a temporary solution as "the fetch fix for RN should be released this week" (back in 2021). Are you sure this is what I need now? Again, I think it's strange that the data sometimes loads (slowly, and there is a limit(5) in the query too) and sometimes comes back with a 400 error.

Comment: can you refer to this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/71686230/15774176 is it helpful?